# Align checkbox with label and add background color to checked checkboxes

Tags: html, css, list, checkbox

We have the following HTML structure. The `wrapper` element has a `max-width` because we don't want it to be longer then that so we have to have a solution with that attribute applied.

We want to be able to hide the default checkbox so that we can style the checkboxes similar to [Pure CSS custom checkboxes](https://codepen.io/Vestride/pen/dABHx), but have our own styles we want to use the HTML structure is different.

**Questions**

How can we style the checkboxes for both unchecked and checked such that they align and checked ones are shown with `background-color: green`?

**Current output:**

[image: checkbox issue]

**Desired output:**

[image: expected output]

Here is what we have but have not luck. The checkbox is not even showing.

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {

}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {

}

.wrapper {
  // This needs to remain. 
  max-width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
  <li>
     <input type="checkbox">
     <label>
       <span>Clear All</span>
     </label>
  </li>
  <li>
     <input type="checkbox">
     <label>
       <span>Cloud and Data monitoring</span>
     </label>
  </li>
  
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you don't actually have any CSS code to style a custom checkbox. Did you mean to post that part? Right now it just seems like you haven't really paid attention to the link re: how to create custom checkboxes since it's not reflected in your code.

Comment: One key is to hide the default checkbox element styling using CSS, as opposed to trying to change the styling.  The input element still remains even though it is not visible. After that, you then include a span or other element that you can style to get the checkbox background look that you want. Here's a great example on w3schools with helpful comments as well: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more ways. For example.

```
input[type='checkbox'] {float: left;}
input[type='checkbox'] + label {display: block; margin-left: 30px;}
```

In real, you use any custom checkboxes, in CSS will be custom element instead of `input[type='checkbox']` of course.

https://jsfiddle.net/1haub3kx/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials and approach to create custom checkboxes with CSS.

The code you provided, does not contain any checkbox styling as Utkanos mentioned.

Try to follow the example [How To Create a Custom Checkbox by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)